# African wild donkey, African wild elephant

Tags: grammaticality

In describing the *African wild donkey or elephant*, *African* is a noun functioning as an adjective, but is *wild* an adjective or a noun? Also, we cannot refer the noun *African* to animals, but can we say: *The wild donkey is African* or, *The elephant is African?*

Answer (score 1):

African is not a noun, it's an adjective. So as wild.

you have to consider the order of adjectives; check the link:

http://www.gingersoftware.com/content/grammar-rules/adjectives/order-of-adjectives/

Comment: But a person born and living in the continent Africa is an African, and that is a noun. One African, two Africans.

Comment: There's a typo: so "as" wild

Comment: The typical order of adjectives is a red herring here. There's actually an important piece of information buried in the ordering. A "wild African elephant" is a member of the species *Loxodonta africana* or *Loxodonta cyclotis* which may come from or live in any country, so long as it's not in a zoo. An "African wild elephant" is an elephant of any species, such as the Asian elephant (*Elephas maximus*) living in the wild in Africa. The fact that these two sets are the same is little more than coincidence.

Comment: @HMac I think you meant to say *"**In this example** African is not a noun, it's an adjective"*